# how to delete all elements with a certain class from a page in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

say there are elements in a website I'm using have elements with classes 'aaa' 'bbb' 'ccc', and I wanna delete or set display:none for all elements with the class 'bbb', how can I go about doing this, changing attributes of elements locally on a website I'm visiting? I know there's inspect element->delete element but there are a lot of them and I want the browser to do this automatically every time I open the site.

Comment: please show some code of what you've attempted

Comment: Related Q&A may be of use, Change default CSS for Google Chrome https://superuser.com/questions/52967/change-default-css-of-google-chrome ... TLDR `--enable-user-stylesheet` when starting Chrome _should_ enable loading custom CSS rules.

Answer (score 2):

you can write a simple chrome extension that will run in each site you visit.
in the extension you need to run:

```
const classArr = document.querySelectorAll(".yourClassName")
```

After you got all of them - you run over each one end set style.display to none

```
for(let elm of classArr){
    elm.style.display = "none"
}
```

Comment: thank you, I'm really new at this I'll look into doing that

Comment: https://github.com/YosiLeibman/chrome-extention-neshei
repository from my GitHub that make something similar

Comment: okay I installed an extension called stylebot that lets you overwrite css of the webpage, I typed in .bbb {display:none} and it's working like I wanted it to now, thanks for all the help and comments

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution on how to remove them completely instead of display none
be careful of the array mutation, because of it you will always be deleting the first element in the array until the array get's emtpy

demo example: https://jsfiddle.net/o7dzgbcm/

HTML

```
<div class='aaa'>
  aaa1
</div>

<div class='bbb'>
  bbb
  <div class='aaa'>
    aaa2
  </div>
</div>

<div class='ccc'>
  ccc
</div>
```

JS

```
const arrHtml = document.getElementsByClassName('aaa');

while (!!arrHtml.length) {
  arrHtml[0].parentNode.removeChild(arrHtml[0])
}
```

And here is a function on how you can change between display none and removing the elements completely out of the DOM

```
function clearElements(className, arg) {
  const arrHtml = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  if (arg === 'none') {
    for (let i = 0; i < arrHtml.length; i++) {
      arrHtml[i].style.display='none'
    }
  } else {
    while (!!arrHtml.length) {
      arrHtml[0].parentNode.removeChild(arrHtml[0])
    }

  }
}
// display none
clearElements('none', "aaa");
// remove the elements
clearElements('aaa')
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider your class name as hidingclass, you can use

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".hidingclass").hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

First install uBlock Origin if you haven't already, then right click the Hindsight 2020 popup, then click block element.